# C# Parameter is Not Valid Error

Tags: c#, exception

I keep getting an error in the following code when I close the print preview window or move the print preview window.  I can't seem to understand why this is happening.  It happens on the g.DrawString() line.  As far as I can tell nothing has been disposed of either.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);

        float width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, this.Font).Width;
        float height = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, this.Font).Height;

        float radius = 0f;

        if (ClientRectangle.Width < ClientRectangle.Height)
            radius = ClientRectangle.Width * 0.9f / 2;
        else
            radius = ClientRectangle.Height * 0.9f / 2;

        switch (orientation)
        {
            case Orientation.Rotate:
                {
                    double angle = (_rotationAngle / 180) * Math.PI;
                    g.TranslateTransform(
                        (ClientRectangle.Width + (float)(height * Math.Sin(angle)) - (float)(width * Math.Cos(angle))) / 2,
                        (ClientRectangle.Height - (float)(height * Math.Cos(angle)) - (float)(width * Math.Sin(angle))) / 2);
                    g.RotateTransform((float)_rotationAngle);
                    g.DrawString(Text, this.Font, textBrush, 0, 0);
                    g.ResetTransform();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

First part of the error:

```
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString(String s, Font font, Brush brush, RectangleF layoutRectangle, StringFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString(String s, Font font, Brush brush, Single x, Single y)
   at ScanPro.CustomControls.UserLabel.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: System.ArgumentException {"Parameter is not valid."}

Comment: Text = 

public override string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                text = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

Comment: You are not disposing of your brushes...

Comment: Ed, I wrapped the Brush in a using statement and it is still throwing the error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I encountered the same error not long ago. The reason was that one of the objects was already disposed...

Maybe the font is being disposed somewhere else, or the graphics object itself. I don't think the brush would cause problems though because it's local to the method and we see that it's not disposed.

**Edit:**

To know whether or not a graphics object is disposed is easy: all of it's properties throw an exception. It's not as easy for a font though, because all properties still work. One way that I found to check whether the font is disposed or not is to try to clone it (you can add font.Clone() in the Watch window to test it). If the clone works, the the font is not disposed. Otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: I don't see anything as disposed though.  It is just confusing because everything I draw to Print Preview is being drawn from it's own class so I don't understand why it is even touching the form is doing.

Comment: Check my edit, a disposed font still displays all of it's properties as if it's not disposed.

Comment: I have narrowed it now to it throwing the exception at this.Font.GetHeight().  Any ideas?

Comment: Just ran a quick test and Font.GetHeight throws an exception when the font is disposed. So that's the problem. The font is being disposed after it has been drawn for the first time, so on the second pass, it fails. Check all references to the form's Font property and make sure it doesn't get disposed.

Comment: @Meta-Knight I checked with my case the brush get disposed second time. You are life saver. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to explicitly have your x/y coordinates be float (i.e. 0.0f instead of 0)? I would expect a compile error from that, not a runtime error so probably not.

Comment: I switched that over to what you suggested and I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had done that much with OnPaint... Everything you show is about Rectangles.  Are you rotating a rectangle or a string?  If it is a rectangle shouldn't it be .DrawRectangle instead of .DrawString?

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody has the same error, I found out that performing the transformations in "separate steps" solves the problem.

```
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
                {


                    wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                    graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);

                }              
            }

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                var font = new Font(new FontFamily("Arial"), 16, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.DrawString("text to add", font, brush, 10F, 10F);
                font.Dispose();
                brush.Dispose();
            }
```